# Understanding problem statement in mathematical modeling by Heinz

Tags: numerical-methods, mathematical-modeling

The problem statement from S. Heinz "Mathematical modeling" goes as follows

[image]

I have a problem understanding what the statement of the problem means. In particular, "Use the data to graph $T$ and $CO_{2}$ as functions of $t$". Am I supposed to just graph the data points? Or use a Lagrangian interpolation? The only technique of modelling data that has been introduced is that of linear models and the polynomial models using the Lagrangian interpolation.

In the $CO_{2}$ figure when the question asks to graph a linear function which approximates the $CO_{2}$ data does this mean a polynomial of first order or should I just choose an arbitrary linear function?

Edit: I am allowed to use Mathematica or Maple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case it is not said how good the approximation has to be, or by what measure its quality is determined. You could just draw any line that goes through the middle of the point cloud, or you could do linear regression.

In the second case you are asked to find two lines where one is above the point cloud and one below, every point of the data between them, both somewhat parallel and as close together as possible. There might be different combinations of sides of the convex hull of the data cloud that fit that description. Then from those two lines compute the arithmetic average, which is a line that goes through the point cloud and thus approximates it in the first sense. To call it "best model" again assumes a measure of quality that is not provided or alluded to (at least not in that snippet).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I searched the pdf of the book for the word "best". On p. 21, the author divides a model into two categories: reasonable model and optimal model and each has different criteria/properties. Basic properties of a $\textbf{reasonable model}$ are: (i) Agreement with the trend of observations. (ii) Agreement with observations over a certain data range of one case. (iii) Information in addition to observations results from using a function. (iv) Interpolation and extrapolation of
information given by observations.

Comment: Basic properties of an $\textbf{optimal model}$ are: (i) Accurate agreement
with observations. (ii) Accurate agreement with all observations
of one class of problems. (iii) Information in addition to observations
results from a model concept. (iv) Valuable new insight into the
mechanisms of observed processes.

Comment: This all sounds very hand-wavy. What is "agreement", how do you measure "information", "inter- and extrapolation" quality of a model (the general abstract model, like "linear function" etc.) usually can only be tested with a learning and testing data set. If you have enough parameters in a model, you can fit it to almost anything with minimal information gain. // These are nice guidelines for thinking about such a process, but not very helpful in solving concrete exercises.